# Comparing two JSON arrays in Karate DSL

Tags: karate

I have to compare two JSON arrays,
one has the value as ["123.45"] and the other has value ["     123.45"]
How to iterate and remove the spaces?
The 2nd array value has spaces before the actual value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `karate.map()` for transforms: https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-transforms

```
* def before = [" 123.45 "]
* def fun = function(x){ return x.trim() }
* def after = karate.map(before, fun)
* match after == ['123.45']
```